# How to lower android emulator performance for testing

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there any way to lower android emulator performance so I can see what will happen when a user with slow device uses my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find different cellular networks in emulator settings, such as **Full, LTE, EDGE**, etc. The **signal strength** can also be changed.

Changing that would give you an idea of how your app behaves.

You may also change some `emulator` **GPU** or **RAM** settings (`-gpu <value>`, `-no-accel`, `-lowram`, etc.) and use ARM images instead of x86 to force slower emulation but their help understanding how you app experience would be on a slower device might be limited.

Finally, you can also pass options to **qemu** (see the list running `emulator -qemu -h`).